# В зависимости от условия помещать данные выбранные курсором, в одну или другую запись

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Можно ли в зависимости от условия помещать данные выбранные курсором, то в одну запись, то в другую.

Примерно так:

```
fetch tbl_dat into 
 if p = 1 then
    dat_rec1
 else
    dat_rec2
end if;
```

Нужно для организации выборки из разных структур, а как динамически менять тип записи (ее состав) не знаю.

То есть:

1. Есть динамический курсор, обращающийся к разным структурам
2. Нужно поместить данные, которые он выбрал в запись
3. Но эта запись должна зависеть от структуры данных в курсоре

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, для этого есть [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9) пакет.

Процедура, которая может поместить результат в два явно не совместимых типа записи:

```
create or replace procedure printRow (what varchar2) is
    nc number; 
    res number;
    type rowType1 is record (id number, item varchar2 (32));
    type rowType2 is record (item varchar2 (32), id number);
    row1 rowType1;
    row2 rowType2;
    cols dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    ncol number;
    resType varchar2 (8);
begin
    nc := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse (nc, what, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns (nc, ncol, cols);
    if cols(1).col_name = upper ('id') and cols(1).col_type = 2 then 
        resType := 'rowtype1';
        dbms_sql.define_column (nc, 1, row1.id); 
        dbms_sql.define_column (nc, 2, row1.item, 32);
    elsif cols(1).col_name = upper ('item') and cols(1).col_type = 1 then 
        resType := 'rowtype2';
        dbms_sql.define_column (nc, 1, row2.item, 32); 
        dbms_sql.define_column (nc, 2, row2.id);
    else
        raise_application_error (-20000, 'illegal type/name: '||cols(1).col_type||'/'||cols(1).col_name);
    end if;

    res := dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch (nc, exact=>true);

    if resType = 'rowtype1' then
        dbms_sql.column_value (nc, 1, row1.id);
        dbms_sql.column_value (nc, 2, row1.item);
        dbms_output.put_line (resType||'='||row1.id||'/'||row1.item); 
    elsif resType = 'rowtype2' then
        dbms_sql.column_value (nc, 1, row2.item);
        dbms_sql.column_value (nc, 2, row2.id);
        dbms_output.put_line (resType||'='||row2.item||'/'||row2.id); 
    end if;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(nc);
end printRow;
/
```

Результат каждого запроса будет помещён в соответствующий ему тип записи:

```
exec printRow (q'[select 1 id, cast('item1' as varchar (32)) item from dual]')
```

> rowtype1=1/item1

```
exec printRow (q'[select cast('item2' as varchar (32)) item, 2 id from dual]')
```

> rowtype2=item2/2

Следует учесть, что использование динамического SQL, не самое производительное решение.